# Prevent modal popup reopen, angular 5 ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, modal-dialog, angular5

I am using following line of code to open modal popup.

```
import { ModalController} from 'ionic-angular';

  openModal()
  {
    const modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
    modal.present();
  }
```

Now, from local notification click event, it opens modal popup. Everytime I click notification it open modal, I want that if modal popup is already opened in application, it should not reopen it.

**How can I prevent modal from reopening?**

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First attempt: (track modal open status with flag)

```
import { ModalController} from 'ionic-angular';

  private modalOpen:boolean = false;
  openModal()
  {
    if (!this.modalOpen){
      this.modalOpen = true;
      const modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
      modal.present();
    }
  }
```

and on the dismiss function add `this.modalOpen = false`

Second attempt: (create Modal only once)

```
 import { ModalController} from 'ionic-angular';

  private modal;
  constructor(){
    this.modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
  }
  openModal()
  {
    this.modal.present();
  }
```

**Edit after comments** Third attempt: (track openState in Provider/Store)

```
import { StateProvider } from 'yourStateProvider';
import { ModalController} from 'ionic-angular';

  constructor(private state:StateProvider){}

  openModal()
  {
    if (!this.stateProvider.modalOpen){
      this.stateProvider.modalOpen = true;
      const modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
      modal.present();
    }
  }
```

ModalPage.ts

```
import { StateProvider } from 'yourStateProvider';

  constructor(private state:StateProvider){}

  dismiss(){
    this.stateProvider.modalOpen = false;
  }
```

StateProvider.ts

```
public modalOpen:boolean = false;
```

Comment: Here, I am using effects import { Actions, Effect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
 and providers to open modal. So, modalOpen:boolean = true;
will be in provider. and  modalOpen:boolean = false;
in modal page. so, I can't use a variable here.

Comment: what's about the second attempt?

Comment: Thanks for the help.But in my code I am listening pubnub external alerts to show popup, that's why constructor will be called multiple time.

Comment: when you have to share the state of the modal between different pages/components you can use a shared provider. (see edit)

Comment: yes, exactly.  Now here, in your provider you need to import page to open modal this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage); And in your page, you are using provider variable to set false, so you need to add provider in page. I used same thing and got a circular dependency error.

Comment: nope. The StateProvider is only to track the state of your app. all functionality has to be in other providers. so you didn't get circular dependencies

Comment: Right @fastr.de .  I used here helper to handle modalOpen boolean variable. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

```
import {Modal} from "ionic-angular/components/modal/modal";
import {ModalOptions} from "ionic-angular/components/modal/modal-options";
import {ModalController} from "ionic-angular";

export class ModalHelper {
  protected modal:Modal;
  protected isModalIsOpen:boolean=false;

  constructor(protected modalCtrl:ModalController) {

  }
  /**
   * opens a modal
   * @param component
   * @param data
   * @param {ModalOptions} opts
   */
  openModal (component: any, data?: any, opts?: ModalOptions) {
    if (this.isModalIsOpen === false) {
      this.modal = this.modalCtrl.create(component, data, opts);
      this.modal.present().then(()=>{
        this.isModalIsOpen = true;
      });
      this.modal.onDidDismiss(()=>{
        this.isModalIsOpen = false;
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I used openModal helper to open a modal from provider by usinf following line of code:

Provider: 
**my-provider.providers.ts**

```
import { ModalController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ModalHelper} from "../../../helper/modal.helper";

  openModal()
  {
    this.modalHelper.openModal(ModalPage);
  }
```